# Button Position in a panel with a scroll

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, button, panel

I have a problem with the position of a button in a panel with a scroll please help here is the jsfiddle``
http://jsfiddle.net/0qy7L0zz/3/

```
<div id="New" class="modalPopup">
<p>dfssfddfdfdfsdfdf</p>
<p>ddfssssssssssss</p>
<p>dsfffffffffff</p>
<p>sdffffffffffff</p>
<p>dsffffffffff</p>
<p>dsfffffffffff</p>
<p>sdfffffffffffff</p>
<p>dsfffffffffff</p>
<p>dfsssssssssss</p>
<button id="New" class="btnClose">ClickME</button>
```

I want the button to be in the right bottom, but it's in the bottom right of the height of the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.btnClose {
   float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/0qy7L0zz/7/

You do mean inside the scrolling .modalPopup right?

Comment: no need to specify the position though. updated fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/0qy7L0zz/8/